# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.views/Home'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I am trying to implement Vue router inside a Laravel application. I have installed vue and vue-router with npm install. This is my package.json, error message, and code  [image: error][image: code]

[image: packagejson]

Comment: Can you try it by adding the .vue extension at the end, like so `import Home from './views/Home.vue'`

Comment: Yes that actually helped since it resulted in a new error. And the fix was adding .vue() to the webpack.mix.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This was the fix]

The fix to the error was adding .vue() in the webpack.mix